# VirtualBox - high performance I/O tuning - is it possible?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, raid, io, performance-tuning

I'm running workstation that heavily relies on virtualization. I chose VirtualBox because:

- unlike VMWare it's free and much more portable and maintenance-free (no need to troubleshoot issues with kernel modules compilation) . I wouldn't like to relay on such software considering how much headache it gave me in the past.
- unlike KVM has GPU acceleration without VGA passthrough. Also it's easy to use and my job requires me to set up LOTS of virutalized environments for  testing software.

However I installed 12 bay software RAID6 array which is supposed to be btrfs based (kernel 4.12 introduces patches for RAID56) so I need bleeding edge kernel. Possibly RC version. All my machines are btrfs based so for compatibility reasons it absolutely makes sense to use btrfs also for RAID.

Primary host OS is isolated from the internet and performs many important tasks I relay on. So I need stable OS here - which collides with btrfs bleeding edge kernel requirement. Thus I'm planning to delegate RAID support to VM and export it back to host over NFS. Before I tested if NFS is compatible with all btrfs functionality and it is so cool - everything should work great.

My plan was flawless:

- KVM virtual machine for RAID support using virtio
- VirtualBox VMs for network and testing lab VMs for work

And it would be perfect - KVM is definitely ideal choice for such workload - it's headless so X crash wouldn't damage RAID, it performs great and it'd be awesome *if*... VirtualBox wouldn't collide with KVM. But it does (KVM machines don't start when VBox machines with VT-x enabled are running and vice versa). So at this point it's quite clear to me that unfortunately I'll need to use VirtualBox for workload it probably was never intended for - high performance i/o. But I don't see  many other choices.

Sorry for this long explanation but it covers why I actually decided to use Virtualbox for such workload instead of KVM despite such decision seems to make no sense. So i hope this thread won't get flooded by *"just use KVM"* answers.

---

### Getting to the point

My question is - does VirtualBox allow any more advanced storage performance tuning like KVM? Is it any close to being capable of reaching ~1000 MB/s sequential read and push it through NFS over localhost? Workstation is connected to 10 gbps backbone so I'd like it to reach anything somewhat close to full potential for fast array synchronization.

Comment: "unlike VMWare it's free and much more portable and maintenance-free (no need to troubleshoot issues with kernel modules compilation)" VMWare player is also free. In the pass VMWare Server is also free. Moreover I also have to recompile the kernel in virtualbox everytime I updated the kernel, because virtualbox additions are not in-tree drivers

Comment: So you want to have a VM guest running that has the RAID setup NFS'd out to the host that then uses this NFS'd share to host more VM's???

Comment: @txtechhelp - yes, exactly. I want VM to support btrfs on block level and export it over NFS back to host so that host won't screw up RAID with its bugged, old, stable kernel.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - I know Player is free but Player allows to run only 1 VM at once and no advanced network config which is deal breaker. VMWare modules compile only on "stable" distributions. If you have Arch or OpenSUSE Tumbleweed or other bleeding edge rolling distro kernel modules often fail to compile at all after update and you need to manually patch kernel modules sources with patches googled around the internet like this one: http://rglinuxtech.com/?p=1932 And if nobody made patch yet then oh well. You have a problem. That's what i meant by "portable" - runs on *any* linux, also rolling.